# changing split method to read from file instead of string

Tags: python, arrays, split

I am trying to convert the following method to allow it to read from a text file instead of reading a list in a string.

This is the method that I found online, and it's working fine with me.

```
str = """
test line1
test line2
test line3
"""    
list = []
for line in str.split("\n"):
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    list.append(line.lstrip())
print (list)
```

I tried to modify the method in order to allow it to read from a text file though I keep getting this error :

> (AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split')

and this is the method that I did.

```
file = open("test.txt","r")
list = []
for line in file.split("\n"):
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    list.append(line.lstrip())
print (list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file` is not a `str`. You can get inner data with `file.read()`.

So, you can do this.

```py
file = open("test.txt", "r")
lst = []
for line in file.read().splitlines():
    if line.strip():
            lst.append(line.lstrip())
print (lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `for line in file:`